# Converting a .txt into a .hprof

Tags: java, heap-dump, hprof

I have a .txt with all the information of the HPROF which I need to analyse, the problem is that when opening it with for example Memory Analyser or any other tool with the same use I get the following error:

> Invalid HPROF file header. (java.io.IOException)
>   Invalid HPROF file header.

Is there any way I could convert this txt into a valid HPROF in order to analyse any memory leaks?

Thanks in advanced for any help provided.

Comment: What is in the .txt? Where did you get it?

Comment: The text contains the whole heap-bump apart from it seems the headers.

Comment: @Ares, still where did you get it? How we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: The file comes from a Service Management application, unable to reproduce the problema as I don't have direct access to the machine.